# Sending XML from AS3 to PHP on Godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have a game that requests and sends high score information at game over. I have the request working so it loads the top ten scores from a mySQL database, but when I try to send from the game to php, I don't get any data. I'm fairly new to PHP and I've been looking at tutorials, but even the simplest things seem to show no data on the PHP side.

AS3

```
private function formatScore():void{
    sendXML = new XML(<score>
                         <points>{playerInfo.pointsTotal}</points>
                         <initials>Ben</initials>
                      </score>);
}

private function saveScores():void{
    sendScoreRequest = new URLRequest(ADD_SCRIPT);
    sendScoreRequest.data = sendXML.toXMLString();
    sendScoreRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    sendScoreRequest.contentType = "text/xml";              
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlSent);
    loader.load(sendScoreRequest);
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
//--- load in xml from flash ---
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$scoreXML = simplexml_load_string($data);
?>
```

Any help would be awesome, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you get some results, and hopefully get you on your way.

```
private function formatScore():void{
    sendXML = new XML(<score>
                         <points>{playerInfo.pointsTotal}</points>
                         <initials>Ben</initials>
                      </score>);
}

private function saveScores():void{
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.scoreXML = sendXML.toXMLString();

    sendScoreRequest = new URLRequest(ADD_SCRIPT);
    sendScoreRequest.data = variables;
    sendScoreRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    sendScoreRequest.contentType = "text/xml";              
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlSent);
    loader.load(sendScoreRequest);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  //--- load in xml from flash ---
  $data = $_POST['scoreXML'];
  $scoreXML = simplexml_load_string($data);
?>
```

Comment: For all intents and purposes, I know that should work, but it's still not putting anything into the database. I tried basically copying and pasting what you gave, but I still didn't get anything. Just to make sure it reads simpleXML properly, I created a new simpleXML object in php and had it read from that instead, which DID send something. So it's either not parsing the data correctly, not sending it correctly, or godaddy has something in place to mess with POST data.